# Make div with display:table have 100% height of parent div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a div with `display:table` fill 100% of its parent div. Here is the div structure:

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="header"></div>
   <div id="body">
       <div id="mytablediv">
    <div class="row">
             <div id="left"> </div>
             <div id="content">&nbsp; </div>
                 <div id="right"> </div>
            </div>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS:

```css
html, body { margin:0; padding:0; height:100%; }
#container { min-height:100%; position:relative; }
#header { background:#ff0; padding:10px; }
#body { padding:10px; padding-bottom:60px; }
#footer { position:absolute; bottom:0; width:100%; height:60px;background:#6cf;
}
#mytablediv { display:table; }
#row { display:table-row; }
#left, #content, #right {display:table-cell;}
#left, #right {background-color:red;}
```

That's my full code. Now what I really want to do for `#mytablediv` is to fill the entire white space between the header and the footer.

Here is a [live jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/A4c8n/).

Comment: height:100% for #body, as well as <body> tag.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`inheritance`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#inheritance) property here and just use the following for `#mytablediv`

```
#mytablediv {
    height: inherit;
}
```

You have specified `div#container` as 100% height, you would need to assign the above property to `div#body` to get the desired result.

Comment: Its parent doesn't have a height specified, though. Its parent is `div#body`, not `body`.

Answer (score 1):

For a percentage height to work on `#mytablediv` (or any other element for that matter), it's parent must have some kind of `height` set on it. That parent's `height` can be a percentage too, but, in that case, for that percentage to work, it's own parent (`#mytablediv`'s grandparent) must also have some kind of `height` set on it. And this goes all the way up to the `html` element.

In your case, if you want the `#mytablediv` to have `100%` of the `height` of the page (window actually), then you'll want the "specific `height`" to be `100%` on all of the ancestors.

```
html,
body,
#container,
#body {
    height: 100%
}

/* now this works */
#mytablediv {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Here's a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/u4hezyav/

Comment: height : 100% doesnt work best in this situation. Its because the there are two other div's , the header and the footer. and the height 100% makes the content height 100%. what should happen is the header+content+footer = 100% height

Answer (score 0):

Atlast, I decided its a job for jQuery.

```
function heightAutomate() {
    var bodyHeight = $("body").height();
    var viewportHeight = $(window).height();
    var shudbe_bf_Height = $("body").height() - 153; /*153:height of div+footer*/
    var real_bf_Height = $("#mytablediv").height();

    if (real_bf_Height < shudbe_bf_Height) {
        $("#bodyfix").css({"height":shudbe_bf_Height});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use a slightly different structure of your HTML portion in order to achieve the desired result. I'm facing the same problem and I used the solution as it is described in this:

http://jsfiddle.net/92y9L/

The related code:

**CSS**

```
*{
    margin:0;
    border:0;
    padding:0;
}
.outer
{
    position:relative;
    width:250px; 
    height:350px;
    border:1px dotted black;
    margin:-1px;
}
.tbl
{
    display:table; 
    width:100%; 
    height:100%;
}
.tr
{
    display:table-row;
}
.td
{
    display:table-cell; 
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center; 
}
.tr .body-outer
{
    height:100%; 
    width:100%; 
}
.body-outer
{
    position:relative;
}
.body-inner
{
    position:absolute; 
    top:0; 
    right:0; 
    bottom:0; 
    left:0; 
    overflow-y:auto; 
    overflow-x:auto;
}
.stretch-x
{
    width:100%;
}
.stretch-y
{
    height:100%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<body>
<div class="outer">
<div class="tbl">
    <div class="tr" style="background-color:Red;">
        <p>test paragraph. This is used as placeholder<br />new line....</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tr stretch-y" style="background-color:Gray;">
        <div class="td stretch-y" style="background-color:Blue;">
            <div class="body-outer" style="background-color:Green;">
                <div class="body-inner">
                <p style=" white-space:nowrap;">test paragraph. This is used as placeholder<br />new line....</p>
                <p>test paragraph. This is used as placeholder</p>
                <p>test paragraph. This is used as placeholder<br />new line....</p>
                <p>test paragraph. This is used as placeholder</p>
                <p>test paragraph. This is used as placeholder<br />new line....</p>
                <p>test paragraph. This is used as placeholder</p>
                <p>test paragraph. This is used as placeholder<br />new line....</p>
                <p>test paragraph. This is used as placeholder</p>
                <p>test paragraph. This is used as placeholder<br />new line....</p>
                <p>test paragraph. This is used as placeholder</p>
                <p>test paragraph. This is used as placeholder<br />new line....</p>
                <p>test paragraph. This is used as placeholder</p>
                <p>test paragraph. This is used as placeholder<br />new line....</p>
                <p>test paragraph. This is used as placeholder</p>
                <p>test paragraph. This is used as placeholder<br />new line....</p>
                <p>test paragraph. This is used as placeholder</p>
                <p>test paragraph. This is used as placeholder<br />new line....</p>
                <p>test paragraph. This is used as placeholder</p>
                <p>test paragraph. This is used as placeholder<br />new line....</p>
                <p>test paragraph. This is used as placeholder</p>

            </div>
            </div>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tr" style="background-color:Red;">
        <p>test paragraph. This is used as placeholder<br />new line.</p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

The concept of this approach is to use an inner css table with three css table rows under the boundaries of an outer container. The upper css row is used to host the header and the lower one to host the footer. Both of them are auto sized based on their content.

The middle row, which is used as the body container, is stretched by setting the height equals to 100%. Concerning the inner content of the "body" css row has been used the outer-relative/inner-absolute layout technique in order to force content to be fitted inside the boundaries of the "body" css row and to allow overflowing. The intermediate css table cell is required by IE in order to work the requirement of stretching.

This design works perfectly with FF+Chrome+Opera+Safari but IE refuses to calculate the height of the "body" content relatively to its ancestor, the css table row, and it persists to correlate it with the height of the outer div. This is exactly the issue that I'm facing.

In summary, in case that there isn't an issue if IE shifts the body content, this solution could be useful for you.